# Connection dialogue box does not appear

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When I open it, the connection dialogue box does not show what [dialogue box does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxdp.png) usually appears. I tried opening it again but it does not appear.

Comment: *"When I open it the connection dialogue box does not what [dialogue box does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxdp.png) usually appears."* This sentence does not make sense. Can you try to reword it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
File->object explorer
```

[image]

Then the connect messagabox will appear

Comment: there is no such option

Comment: Can you add in your post a screenshot of the file menu?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for Connect Object Explorer under File? Clicking that will bring up the pop up that usually appears at the start.

[image: Connect Object Explorer]

Comment: There is no object explorer option